# How to start OWASP ZAP proxy with Chrome webdriver and java?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, owasp, zap

I download today (13-05-2020) a new OWASP ZAP. I regenerate root CA certificate. I configure local proxy to localhost:8092

[image]

After un run a simple java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
    proxy.setAutodetect(false);
    proxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:8092");
    proxy.setSslProxy("localhost:8092");

    final OperatingSystem currentOperatingSystem = OperatingSystem.getCurrentOperatingSystem();
    String pathWebdriver = String.format("src/test/resources/drivers/%s/googlechrome/%s/chromedriver%s", currentOperatingSystem.getOperatingSystemDir(),
            SystemArchitecture.getCurrentSystemArchitecture().getSystemArchitectureName(), currentOperatingSystem.getSuffixBinary());

    if (!new File(pathWebdriver).setExecutable(true)) {
        logger.error("ERROR when change setExecutable on " + pathWebdriver);
    }

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", pathWebdriver);
    final ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");

    chromeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
    chromeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    chromeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        //driver.get("http://www.google.com/ncr");

        // www.google.com work (OWASP ZAP list all requests) but not localhost
        driver.get("http://localhost:8080/ui");

    }
    driver.quit();
}
```

Selenium script run OK but OWASP ZAP don not intercept any requests.

[image]

Comment: You haven't set the https proxy, or set all proxies the same in chrome

Comment: @kingthorin, thank you. I add `proxy.setSslProxy("localhost:8092");` call to google work but if I want test a localhost application (`http://localhost:8080/ui` do not work again.

Comment: workaround for localhost: I create a DNS in etc/host

Comment: OH there's a bunch of prefs and stuff you have to set to work with localhost. I can dig it up if you need to know.

Comment: @kingthorin, yes, please, please

Comment: Answer added, that addresses both points+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to ensure you include SSL proxy details (along side the HttpProxy details), ex:
`proxy.setSslProxy("<proxy-host>:<proxy-port>");`, or more specifically `proxy.setSslProxy("localhost:8092");` for your code

To be able to proxy localhost in modern versions of Chrome you need to remove loopback from the proxy bypass list as follows: 
`--proxy-bypass-list=<-loopback>`, or in your code specifically: `chromeOptions.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=<-loopback>");`

You may also want to consider adding: `chromeOptions.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");`